# How to do Mass insertion in Redis using JAVA?

Tags: java, redis, jedis

Hi I need to do multiple insertions of the form

SADD key value

I have the key value pair and needed to know how to perform mass insertions using JAVA . I have written a file in the Redis Protocol. How to proceed further

Comment: Could you post your file?

Comment: it has commands of the form *3\r\n$4\r\nSADD\r\n$3\r\nkey\r\n$5\r\nvalue\r\n as given in the link http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have inputs written to Redis protocol format then why don't just use pipe mode of redis-cli or nc? It's explained from http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert.

If you have mass (key, value) inputs then you can use Jedis to perform sadd with pipelining to get higher performance.

Below example assumes that iter (Iterator) has elements each item is key"\t"value form.

```
try (Jedis jedis = new Jedis(host, port)) {
  Pipeline pipeline = jedis.pipelined();
  while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String[] keyValue = iter.next().split("\t");
    pipeline.sadd(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    // you can call pipeline.sync() and start new pipeline here if you think there're so much operations in one pipeline
  }
  pipeline.sync();
}
```

Comment: safe to mention that this feature is on unstable branch

Comment: No, document is outdated. It is available from 3.0.0-beta. Please refer https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/088c508abc89b66ce14870a2abe06879238a3b21 and see tags.

Comment: redis-cli --pipe not working in 3.0.1 while if i use only redis-cli its working

Comment: OK its fixed i was not adding "\r\n" at the end of command properly  . currently I am executing as a command line operation using the command  Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{ "bash" , "-c" , "cat  somefile.txt | redis-cli --pipe"}); any default way to do it in JAVA ??

Comment: No, I think you're doing well. If you have bulk (key, value) pairs instead of protocol format, source code in answer may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the actual read/write operations through Spring *CacheManager* with *RedisTemplate* configured to use Redis as the cache, you can also use the *executePipelined* method of RedisTemplate which takes a callback as an argument. The callback needs to define the *doInRedis* method which does the work (read/write operations) in Redis that you want to do in a batch.

Following code shows inserting a List of objects wrapped in a CacheableObject interface that has a getKey() and getValue() by calling *redisTemplate.opsForHash().put()*.

```
@Component
public class RedisClient {
  @Autowired
  RedisTemplate redisTemplate;  
  
  //batch-insert using Redis pipeline, a list of objects into the cache specified by cacheName
  public void put(String cacheName, List<CacheableObject> objects) {
    try {
      this.redisTemplate.executePipelined(new RedisCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
          for(CacheableObject object: objects) {
            redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(cacheName, object.getKey(), object.getValue()); 
          }
          return null;
        }
      });
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error inserting objects into Redis cache: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

RedisTemplate itself is configured using a configuration class such as the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport implements 
                                                               CachingConfigurer {

  @Value("${redis.hostname}")
  private String redisHost;
  @Value("${redis.port}")
  private int redisPort;
  @Value("${redis.timeout.secs:1}")
  private int redisTimeoutInSecs;
  @Value("${redis.socket.timeout.secs:1}")
  private int redisSocketTimeoutInSecs;
  @Value("${redis.ttl.hours:1}")
  private int redisDataTTL;

  @Bean
  JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
     RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
     return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
  }
 
  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<Object, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return redisTemplate;
}   

  @Bean
  public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager (JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = 
            RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().disableCachingNullValues()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(redisDataTTL)) .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(RedisSerializer.java()));
    redisCacheConfiguration.usePrefix();
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = 
            RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.
            fromConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();
    redisCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true);
    return redisCacheManager;
}

  @Bean
  public JedisPoolConfig poolConfig() {
    final JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
    jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxTotal(100);
    jedisPoolConfig.setMaxIdle(100);
    jedisPoolConfig.setMinIdle(10);
    jedisPoolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
    jedisPoolConfig.setTestWhileIdle(true);
    return jedisPoolConfig;
}

  @Override
  public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new RedisCacheErrorHandler();
  }
}
```